# UGC-Unchecking properties in CMS comments tab not working

Tags: 2011, ugc

I am working on User Generated Content feature in Tridion 2011 HR2. When I uncheck the "Show unmoderated comments on this component" and save the components, the options are still checked. How can I uncheck this.

Comment: Were you ever able to get the setting to "stick?" I'd guess it might have been a browser cache issue. One thing I would have tried is also trying to make a small change to the Component's text (to confirm it isn't a bug with saving the data).